# How to read line from file with different types in c

Tags: c, scanf

```
struct bank{
struct branch *branches;
struct operation_type *optypes;};

struct operation_type{
char optname[100];
float commission;
int optnum;
struct operation_type *nextopt;};

void readOperationTypes(char inputFile[100], struct bank* bank){
FILE *file = fopen(inputFile,"r");
if(file != NULL){
    while(fscanf(file, "%s %f", bank->optypes->optname, &bank->optypes->commission) == 1)
        bank->optypes->nextopt = bank->optypes;
}
else{
    printf("\nThe file you looking for doesn't exist.");    
}}
```

I'm trying to scan my opt.txt file which context like this

1. EFT 15.6
2. Withdraw 0.9

they don't have numbers at start just text and float. I'm trying to scan a txt file like this and getting nothing in while loop. How can i fix that ?

Comment: Why are you comparing `fscanf` return value to `1` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. because if it's EOF i think it'll automatically break the while

Comment: You should head straight to the [documentation of `fscanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf) and read up the "Return value" section there.

Comment: @EugeneSh. but if i do this without while it scans first line very well but i need to scan all the lines

Comment: I did not say anything about "without while". I just said that your expectation from it to return `1` is not correct.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm checking the return values.

Comment: I'm also afraid that the first `%s` would consume all the line.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni it's not consuming all the line but i replace `1` with `EOF` and made `==` to `!=` but still not reading

Comment: And i tried in another C file without using structs to see my while works and yes it works but with structs it's not working